# builder to update in ChangeNotifierProxyProvider on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, builder, flutter-provider

first thanks for check my question.

I'm a beginner and I have this code :

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ImgProvider>(
          builder: (ctx, auth, previousItem) => ImgProvider(
            auth.token,
            auth.userId,
            previousItem == null ? [] : previousItem.items,
          ),
        ),
```

> ChangeNotifierProxyProvider

'       .
     :

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ImgProvider>(
          update: (ctx, auth, previousItem) => ImgProvider(
            auth.token,
            auth.userId,
            previousItem == null ? [] : previousItem.items,
          ),
```

"  ''  ."

: "        ".
 !

Comment: sorry I didn't understand the last part, `But with the change of builder to create and update on` what do you mean by that, you can still use create and update, builder is when you need to use the provider directly in the next widget and try to avoid boilerplate with using Builder or Consumer

Comment: Thanks for asking.

I mean that in the first time the "ChangeNotifierProxyProvider" have "builder" instead of "update" like the code above is writing.

what I want is : " can you please correct to me this code, please ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution is to change it like this :

```
 ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ImgProvider>(
          create: (ctx) => ImgProvider(),
          update: (ctx, auth, previousItem) => previousItem
            ..receiveToken(
                auth, previousItem == null ? [] : previousItem.items),
        ),
```

and create a function in ImgProvider() like this :

```
void receiveToken(Auth auth, List<ImgVar> items) {
    authToken = auth.token;
    userId = auth.userId;
    _items = items;
  }
```

Comment: but I couldnt fetch the data

Answer (score 2):

if class has constrictor you must make parameters is null like this

```
 ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => Auth()),
      ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ProductsProvider>(
        create: (ctx) => ProductsProvider('', []),
        update: (ctx, auth, previousProductsProviderState) =>
            ProductsProvider(
                auth.token, previousProductsProviderState!.items),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that is working with the up to date version of the provider package. Your **MultiProvider** widget should look like this, and the order of providers is important here, **Auth** should be place before your **ImgProvider**

```dart
MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => Auth()),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, ImgProvider>(
              create: (context) =>
                  ImgProvide(Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).token, Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false).userId),
              update: (_, auth, previous) => ImgProvider(auth.token, auth.userId)),
        ],
       child: ...)
```